# Remove newlines and 2+ spaces/tabs unless between particular tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to take an HTML string and remove all the whitespace except within particular tags where whitespace is necessary such as (but not limited to) `pre`, `textarea`.

I have the following regex which I am then replacing all the matches with an empty string. It is removing all spaces everywhere except for within tags (between attributes, between classes, etc):

```
// Remove 2+ white spaces
string.replace(/(\s\s+)(?![^\<]*\>)/g, ' ')

// Remove new lines
string.replace(/\n(?![^\<]*\>)/g, '')
```

Current output:

```
<div><span>Hi</span> <span>Hello</span></div> <pre>test text</pre>
```

Expected output (space between `> <` are gone, and line breaks persist within pre):

```
<div><span>Hi</span><span>Hello</span></div><pre>
  test text
</pre>
```

Can I somehow combine the two?

What I would like:

1. Replace 2+ white spaces with 1 whitespace except when within particular tags
2. Replace new lines with empty string except when within particular tags

Basically I want to minify an HTML string

Comment: Since you use different replace patterns, you can't do it in one regex.

Comment: The replacement can be within a callback function...

Comment: BTW: You can't replace Spaces in a pre or textarea, they will change output shown.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the question so it now specifies that.

Comment: Well, I'm not a fan of one liners, if a two liner perform better.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn try something like this: `(<pre>\s+</pre>)|\s+. Then pass a callback to the replace function and only replace it if p1 (the first captured group) isn't a string. Basically, test against each of the tags that you don't want to replace, and only replace if none of the capturing groups are valid.

Comment: Also, you can't remove the Space here: </span><span>. That will change output.

Comment: This shouldn't be tried with regex. Use dom parser to rebuild dom.

Comment: @revo, I am using node, so dom parser won't work.

Comment: Then please add `node.js` tag too. Aren't you able to install a corresponding module?

Comment: I was trying to do it in a simple way, but it looks like just using [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) will do the trick.